# Crash on insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xmpp, openfire

I have chat app, I fetching history from server and it get it one-by-one message, so I fetch one message and add it to array and insert row to table.. and this process is very fast.

Here is code :

```
-(void)msgRecevied:(NSMutableDictionary *)messageContent
{
        if([chatWithUser isEqualToString:[messageContent objectForKey:kReceiver_User]])
            return;

        NSString *m = [messageContent objectForKey:kMsg];
        [messageContent setObject:[m substituteEmoticons] forKey:kMsg];
        [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kTrnDate] forKey:kTrnDate];
        [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kSender_User] forKey:kSender_User];
        [messageContent setObject:[messageContent objectForKey:kReceiver_User] forKey:kReceiver_User];

        NSMutableDictionary *arrayTemp1 = [messageContent mutableCopy];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


            [app.Glb.arrayChat addObject:arrayTemp1];
            numberOfRows  = app.Glb.arrayChat.count;

            if([app.Glb.arrayChat count] > 0)
            {

                [self.tblChatting beginUpdates];
                NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[app.Glb.arrayChat count]-1 inSection:0];
                [self.tblChatting insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                [self.tblChatting endUpdates];

                [self.tblChatting scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath
                                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                                animated:YES];
                newIndexPath = nil;
            }
        });
}
```

but I am getting crash to `endUpdates` that :

```
2016-09-03 10:47:32.638 [313:50270] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2379f98b 0x22f3ae17 0x236b4e1f 0x2804372b 0x27d43a19 0x27d5aaa3 0x27f1a741 0x27efe987 0x7e93b 0x7a7b7f 0x7a7b6b 0x7ac655 0x23761bdd 0x237600d7 0x236af2e9 0x236af0d5 0x24c9fac9 0x27d740b9 0x39424d 0x23357873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: first check where your app is crashing. -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil suggest that you are inserting nil in your Mutable Array.

Comment: but i didn't use insertObject: in my class

Answer (score 0):

check that you are getting data in `messageContent` because error says that you are adding nil object to array. If you are getting data from server then you should call `msgRecevied` method from the `completion handler` of your server call or network call. second thing you not need to  insert rows. just add new objects in your array (which is used as data source) and just `relaod` tableview after that so `cellforrowatindexpath` will manage all the things.

Comment: yes reloadData works, but it failed some time , that it not adding message cell to table. so come up with this solution. and messageContent is not nill that i checked.

Comment: No, im saying i know that reloadData solve my problem but it getting error when user send message that time table not adding row to table... so i come up with this solution that insert row to table instead of reloading table

Comment: then that must be the problem of your data source. you should manage `cellForRowAtIndexpath` which depends on your array and return cell as per your array!!

Comment: new object adding to arrayChat and reload table..  but it's not adding row. im getting numberOfRow increase but row not added to table.

Comment: show your `cellforrow` method and your array in question!!